# Unable to Split String after Converting Object to Array in Meteor.JS Handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, handlebars.js

A Handlebar helper `arrarify` is used to convert an object of objects into an array of objects

**handlebarsHelper.js**

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('arrayify',function(obj){
    result = [];
    for (var key in obj) result.push({name:key,value:obj[key]});
    return result;
});
```

**client/views/main.html**

```
<template name="orderList">
    {{#each arrayify orderList}}
        {{value.amount}} {{ value.name }}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

**client/views/main.js**

```
Template.orderList.orderList = function() {
    // Retrieved from Collection
    orderList = {
        12345: {name: "apples_mackintosh", amount: 10},
        12346: {name: "oranges_sunkiss", amount:5}
    };

    return orderList;
};
```

**Question:** How do I render the template value `oranges_sunkiss` as `oranges`, `apples_mackintosh' as 'apples`? I tried using `.split('_')[0]` but Meteor throws an error

**client/views/main.html**

```
<template name="orderList">
    {{#each arrayify orderList}}
        {{value.amount}} {{ value.name.split('_')[0] }}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

**Error**

```
While building the application:
client/views/main.html:63: Parse error:
...unt}} {{ value.name.split('_')[0] }} @ {
-----------------------^
Expecting 'ID', got 'INVALID'
```

Comment: remove `{{ value.name.split('_')[0] }}` and see the output. I think I know what the problem is, just want to make sure.

Comment: @rdodev If I remove that, no error occurs, everything prints out properly

Comment: but does it print the amounts as expected?

Comment: try `{{ value.name }}` I suspect the arrayify might be messing up the structure.

Comment: @rdodev `{{ value.name }}` prints out `oranges_sunkiss`

Comment: OK, then I'm pretty sure what's happening. Instead of doing the split at the rendering label, do it when you are creating the roderedList in `main.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what's happening is that you are trying to use JS code inside handlebars templates. This is a common issue/annoyance but it's done for a good reason: the actual template should be free of logic and code. Templates should be "dumb" and only for display purposes. For your specific example, move the string split to when you are creating `orderedList` inside `main.js`

```
Template.orderList.orderList = function() {
    // Retrieved from Collection
    orderList = {
        12345: {name: "apples_mackintosh".split('_')[0], amount: 10},
        12346: {name: "oranges_sunkiss".split('_')[0], amount:5}
    };

    return orderList;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

first store it in some variable and then split it via javascript or create some helper function that will be called and return the splited value.